# enabling n mode in hostapd configuration

Tags: wifi

i need to enable n mode of wifi (bgn). i know the wifi configuration is specified in hostapd. but i couldn't find anywhere how to enable 'only n mode' in hostapd. i am using the wl1273l chip , which is capable of bgna. Is there any lines that i need to specify in the hostapd ?.i tried the following 
`ieee80211=1

wmm_enabled=1 
nl80211=1`

but failed. i read the hostapd documentation but there is no data regarding the n mode.only regarding bga. if know anything please answer

Answer (score 3):

These config lines pasted below are the relevant config params for n-mode.
You could check out this conf to lookup any param you want to use for hostapd:

http://w1.fi/gitweb/gitweb.cgi?p=hostap.git;a=blob_plain;f=hostapd/hostapd.conf

An interesting extra to my post:

Just configuring these didn't enable n-mode for my nix router. Turns out hostapd checks for neighboring SSID's. If there are  a lot of those, it won't activate the secondary n channel.
A quick inSSIDer scan showed my my neighbours were in fact using the secondary channel. Apparently many routers don't have this check (as described in RFC) built in.
I used the patch described in the url below to disable the neigboring network check, and force hostapd to run in n-mode.

http://www.brunsware.de/blog/gentoo/hostapd-40mhz-disable-neighbor-check.html

These are the n-mode config lines:

```
# ieee80211n: Whether IEEE 802.11n (HT) is enabled
# 0 = disabled (default)
# 1 = enabled
# Note: You will also need to enable WMM for full HT functionality.
ieee80211n=1
#
# Default WMM parameters (IEEE 802.11 draft; 11-03-0504-03-000e):
# for 802.11a or 802.11g networks
# These parameters are sent to WMM clients when they associate.
# The parameters will be used by WMM clients for frames transmitted to the
# access point.
#
# note - txop_limit is in units of 32microseconds
# note - acm is admission control mandatory flag. 0 = admission control not
# required, 1 = mandatory
# note - here cwMin and cmMax are in exponent form. the actual cw value used
# will be (2^n)-1 where n is the value given here
#
wmm_enabled=1
wmm_ac_bk_cwmin=4
wmm_ac_bk_cwmax=10
wmm_ac_bk_aifs=7
wmm_ac_bk_txop_limit=0
wmm_ac_bk_acm=0
wmm_ac_be_aifs=3
wmm_ac_be_cwmin=4
wmm_ac_be_cwmax=10
wmm_ac_be_txop_limit=0
wmm_ac_be_acm=0
wmm_ac_vi_aifs=2
wmm_ac_vi_cwmin=3
wmm_ac_vi_cwmax=4
wmm_ac_vi_txop_limit=94
wmm_ac_vi_acm=0
wmm_ac_vo_aifs=2
wmm_ac_vo_cwmin=2
wmm_ac_vo_cwmax=3
wmm_ac_vo_txop_limit=47
wmm_ac_vo_acm=0
```

Comment: Is that the same patch as this? https://github.com/ivkos/hostap-force-ht40/commit/004876e562b310d85ffab0f1d671b7a51ff0ce51

Comment: Looking at the description of it, both patches indeed seem to have the same end result. Both patches force a 40mhz channel width regardless of other overlapping wifi networks.